# How to clear selected item Xamarin list

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms app that displays a list of items.  When you select one of the items, the app navigates to a page with some details on it.  This details page also contains the standard Back button which takes you back to the original list.

The problem I am having is that this works fine except for the fact that when I go back to the main list, if I select the same item again, nothing happens.  I have to select some other item on the list which works fine.

I think the previously selected item has to be cleared or something but of the attempts I've tried, it just crashes the app.

Here's the code I am using:

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        string selectedItem = e.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var detailsPage = new ItemDetails(selectedItem); 
        await Navigation.PushAsync(detailsPage);
    };
```

I need something else here to clear the details but when I added in listView.SelectedItem = null; after the await command, it was causing the app to crash when I clicked the back button.

What do I need to add here so I can re-select the same item and go to the details page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.SelectedItem != null) {
      string selectedItem = e.SelectedItem.ToString();

      // clear selected item
      listView.SelectedItem = null;

      var detailsPage = new ItemDetails(selectedItem); 
      await Navigation.PushAsync(detailsPage);
    }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that causes the app to crash when you select an item and doesn't display the details page.

Comment: what's the exception?  AFAIK this is the standard way to un-set the selected item.  You might want to try the ItemTapped event, which doesn't maintain a selected state

Comment: or, try adding an if (e.SelectedItem != null) around your code